# How to make a mat-chip-listbox always has a value

Tags: angular, angular-material

Was wondering how to make a [mat-chip-listbox](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/api) always has at least one value

```html
<mat-chip-listbox
  aria-label="foo-bar"
  formControlName="fooBar"
>
  <mat-chip-option *ngFor="let i of fooBars" [value]="i">
    {{ i }}
  </mat-chip-option>
</mat-chip-listbox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually quite simple

you listen to the [change](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/api#MatChipListbox)

```html
<mat-chip-listbox
  aria-label="foo-bar"
  formControlName="fooBar"
  (change)="patchFooBar($event)"
>
  <mat-chip-option *ngFor="let i of fooBars" [value]="i">
    {{ i }}
  </mat-chip-option>
</mat-chip-listbox>
```

If the value is `undefined` then you patch the value.
Note, you have to put it in a timeout so it will be triggered in the next life circle.

```js
patchFooBar(changes: MatChipListboxChange) {
  if (!changes.value) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Wait next changes
      this.myFormGroup.get('fooBar').patchValue(this.foobars[0])
    }, 0)
  }
}
```

*You could also subscribe to the `myFormGroup.valueChanges` event*